# Splitting shared Apple ID

Tags: iphone, apple-id, sharing

While similar to some questions, I think my question has some unique differences.

My family (mult iphones and iPads) with 6 people.  We have been sharing a single apple ID as we started before the family plan was available.

Finally time to split out.  We are setting up a new iphone 11.

1. I believe that the apps will still be shared as long as the new phone has a new apple ID connected to the family plan. (correct?)
2. But concerned about contacts, calendar, etc.  How can I properly get this  data over?

One thing I've considered is backing up the current phone, installing as is on the new phone with the shared apple ID - and then changing Apple ID on the new phone - but concerned that will then end up with problems.

Any advice from the community how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Apps:
   All Apps that are eligible for family sharing will be available on a new AppleID that is added to Family Sharing.
   Keep in mind that In-App purchases are not shared. More detailed info is available in the [Apple Support Article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203046).
2. A desktop computer (preferably a Mac) would probably be the easiest way to properly distribute the content. Set up both the new and old AppleID and then use the appropriate Apps to move/copy the calendars/events/contacts/...

Comment: Thanks for your input.  So can I backup the old phone onto our MAC, then use that backup onto the new phone, and then change Apple ID?  Not sure of the sequence.

Comment: I wouldn't do it with backups. I assume you regularly sync your iCloud contacts. So set up the iCloud on your mac. And create another new one that you set up on the second phone. Then use the mac so sort the contacts between the accounts.